# .NET Core call WCF: The server name or address could not be resolved error

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I've a .NET Core 2 web api that call a connected WCF service. In my development environment it works fine, but when I deploy it in production environment, with IIS and Kestrel, I get this exception:

```
 System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (There was no endpoint listening at http://192.168.100.33:3433/Test.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.) ---> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at http://192.168.100.33:3433/Test.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The server name or address could not be resolved
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceModelHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered>d__59.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpClientRequestChannel.HttpClientChannelAsyncRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at WebApplication1.Controllers.ValuesController.Get() in c:\temp\TestWS\WebApplication1\Controllers\ValuesController.cs:line 29
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at http://192.168.100.33:3433/Test.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: The server name or address could not be resolved
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequest>d__105.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceModelHttpMessageHandler.<SendAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.<FinishSendAsyncUnbuffered>d__59.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpClientRequestChannel.HttpClientChannelAsyncRequest.<SendRequestAsync>d__13.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.TaskCreator.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<CreateGenericTask>b__0(IAsyncResult asyncResult)<---
```

The same WCF service called by classic web api on the same server works fine.
If I call it by web browser from the server it work fine too.

This is my test code:

```csharp
BasicHttpBinding bindingStr = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress endpointSessionSTR = new EndpointAddress(new Uri("http://192.168.100.33:3433/Test.svc"));

TestStrutture.StruttureClient cliStr = new TestStrutture.StruttureClient(bindingStr, endpointSessionSTR);
var retVal = cliStr.GetClassiStrutturaAsync();

retVal.Wait();
var classi = retVal.Result;
```

What did I forget to do?

Comment: The same code on a .net 4.6.1 web api installed on the same IIS Server works fine... I don't know why Kestrel can't access web service.

Comment: I resolved running this command on the server: netsh winhttp reset proxy.  The server doesn't use proxy to access the network

Answer (score 2):

On CMD:

`netsh winhttp reset proxy`

You can try to list the proxys first using.

`netsh winhttp show proxy`

I have not discovered why this happens, but that did the trick for me. On netcore 2.0 and 2.1.